# Installed MoonRise UI Theme now having snips of code highlighting

Tags: java, eclipse, themes, highlighting

I followed the tutorial for this but at the end of it I was having some highlighting issues in my code. I have been looking for hours and have not seen anyone with the same problem.

This image shows what my screen looks like:

[image: This image shows what my screen looks like]

Comment: thanks for showing me how to display the pictures better user1803551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ***Window > Preferences: General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations*** select ***Warnings*** and change ***Text As:*** from *Box* to ***Native Problem Underline***.