# How to change warning and error highlighted text background color in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I want to change the warning and error highlighted text background color in Eclipse.

[image]

edit:

I have tried `Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors >Annotations > C/C++ Occurrences > Color`[image]

Comment: You're close: instead of _Occurrences_ you have to edit _Errors_ and _Warnings_: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46988988/6505250

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installed MoonRise UI Theme now having snips of code highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988279/installed-moonrise-ui-theme-now-having-snips-of-code-highlighting)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the color is coming from a "highlight" shown for error and warning annotations.

The place to configure these is `Window | Preferences | General | Editors | Text Editors | Annotations`. For each annotation type, you can change the highlight color, or change the style to something other than "highlight" (like "underline").

In your screenshot, it looks like the highlighted annotation types are "Errors" and "Warnings", although there may be others you want to change as well.

Comment: thanks for answer! I had tried your solution.Please take a look at the image I have added in my question.

Comment: @SMITPATIL: You're right, it's not "C/C++ Occurrences" (that wouldn't highlight all three of those lines at the same time). Please see my edit.