# How to remove the highlighted line in Eclipse JSP File

Tags: eclipse, syntax-error, warnings

i have to remove the highlighting color in .jsp file of eclipse.**strong text**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installed MoonRise UI Theme now having snips of code highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988279/installed-moonrise-ui-theme-now-having-snips-of-code-highlighting)

Comment: And also look at this question: [How to change warrning and errored highlighted text background colour in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993032/how-to-change-warrning-and-errored-highlighted-text-background-colour-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Actually i just deleted the metadata folder so all settings which i set is removed.My problem is solved but thanks for other also to answer the question and put effort it will also work.

Comment: By removing your `.metadata`, you have not only deleted all settings and caches, but a lot more. The recommendation to delete the `.metadata` is an unstoppable Stack Overflow hoax which never ever makes sense. In your case, you could have simply created a new workspace and then switched to the old workspace while copying the settings, without losing any unshared launch configuration, losing the whole local history, etc.